# how to upload pdf file in asp.net using FTP mode?

Tags: asp.net

```
public void UploadFTPTextFile(string ftpServer, string ftpFolder, string user, string passward, string NName, FileUpload FileUpload1)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = null;
            string fileName = NName;
            using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
            {
                fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd());
                fileStream.Close();
            }   
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServer + ftpFolder + fileName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, passward);
                request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
                request.EnableSsl = false;
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();
                }
        }
```

I am try upload the pdf file using above code , it upload successfully , but when download it from Web server and open it in acrobat reader , it show error , file is corrupt ? please help me to upload pdf file using FTP mode in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void UploadFTPPdfFile(string ftpServer, string ftpFolder, string user, string passward, string NewName, FileUpload FileUpload1)
        {
            string fileName = NewName;
            System.Net.FtpWebRequest rq = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpServer + ftpFolder + fileName);
            rq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user,passward);
            rq.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;           
            System.IO.Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();
            System.IO.Stream ftpstream = rq.GetRequestStream();
            ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ftpstream.Close();
        }
```